# Laravel : Field 'name' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel, postman

I'm testing the route locally through `postman`, sending `JSON` object with properties and values needed to create an event:

```json
// http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/events
{
    "name": "Event 1",
    "description": "Event 1 description",
    "start_time": "2024-01-01 15:00:00",
    "end_time": "2024-01-01 16:00:00"
    
}
```

##### Model `Event`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class Event extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'start_time',
        'end_time',
        'user_id',
    ];

    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function attendee(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Attendee::class);
    }
}
```

##### `EventController`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Event;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EventController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $event = Event::create([
            $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
                'description'=>'nullable|string',
                'start_time' => 'required|date',
                'end_time'=> 'required|date|after:start_time',
            ]),
            'user_id'=>1
        ]);

        return $event;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error object response:

```
"message": "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `events` (`user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 2023-12-02 18:01:52, 2023-12-02 18:01:52))"
```

reading the message, the controller doesn't seem to receive any data because its not even trying to insert them to the table (name,description,start_time,end_time)

reading about the error, some suggestions is i didn't add these columns to my $fillable, another suggestion is that i'm sending data to the database and exempting fields that are not nullable or fields that can’t be left empty.

but i didn't fall for any of these mistakes, so what could be the issue ?  thanks in advance.

please don't hesitate to ask for another code blocks if needed.
please note that columns and fake data are generated using database factories and seeders.

Also here is the event `migrations`:

```php
<?php

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignIdFor(User::class);
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('start_time');
            $table->dateTime('end_time');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('events');
    }
};
```

Comment: I assume the route is POST. In Postman, which type are you using in Body to send data? I usually use raw directly, but I've heard of bugs with form-data and x-www-form-urlencoded. If that's the case, try using a different approach

Comment: i also use raw data of type JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an array of an array of data instead of an array of data, this will work:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Event;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EventController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'description' => 'nullable|string',
            'start_time' => 'required|date',
            'end_time' => 'required|date|after:start_time',
       ]);

        $event = Event::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'start_time' => $request->start_time,
            'end_time' => $request->end_time,
            'user_id' => 1,
        ]);

        return $event;
    }
}
```

---

Your code is doing this:

```php
$data = $request->validate([
    'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'description' => 'nullable|string',
    'start_time' => 'required|date',
    'end_time' => 'required|date|after:start_time',
]);

$event = Event::create(
    [
        $data,
        'user_id' => 1,
    ]
);
```

So, your data is like this:

```php
$data = [
    0 => [
        'name' => 'name value',
        'description' => 'description value',
        'start_time' => 'start time value',
        'end_time' => 'end time value',
    ],
    'user_id' => 1,
];
```

But you want it to be like this:

```php
$data = [
    'name' => 'name value',
    'description' => 'description value',
    'start_time' => 'start time value',
    'end_time' => 'end time value',
    'user_id' => 1,
];
```

So, indeed, you have `name` missing. That is also way `user_id` is the only value completed on the tried query (check the error), but all the other values are missing.

Comment: thanks, that worked, although i've seen some code examples doing both validation and receiving input in the create method, like i did

Comment: Oh I guess that would be a way to but I'm following this practice from documentation and it would be great you don't hit DB directly in future. Have a great day :)

Comment: @KamranAllana the "why" of your solution is not correct, I will edit your answer with the right explanation. The TL;DR; is because he put an array of an array (indexes issue)

Comment: Appreciated the detailed answer you edited @matiaslauriti 